# Master Detail columns disappear after including toolbar in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, master-detail

After including a toolbar within the master detail layout, the master and detail columns (along with vertical divider) have disappeared for some reason. What needs to be done in order to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <include layout="@layout/myToolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/myToolbar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/master_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :-)